# query in category.php repeats itself

Tags: categories, custom-field, query, php

I'm need some help on my query.

I'm building up a category page where on top a post need to show where custom field key 'uitleg' has value 'ja'. Per category there is only one post with that value. I use this post as an introduction post. Below that post I need to show all other posts in the same category minus the introduction post. This part works like a charm.

But then something strange happens. If I got 4 posts in one category (1 introduction post and 3 other posts) the query below repeated itself 4 times beneath eachother. Is there a way to stop this? Must be in one of my foreach queries. But I can't see where this is going wrong. Anyone can see where this is going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php $drukproef = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'drukproef', $single = true); ?>
                <?php $drukproefimage = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'drukproefimage', $single = true); ?>
                <?php $actief = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'actief', $single = true); ?>
                <?php $uitleg = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'uitleg', $single = true); ?>
                <?php $artistnaam = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'artistnaam', $single = true); ?>
                <?php $artisturl = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'artisturl', $single = true); ?>


                <?php global $post;
                    $categories = get_the_category();
                    foreach ($categories as $category) :
                ?>

                 <?php
                 global $post;
                 $tmp_post = $post;
                 $myposts = get_posts('posts_per_page=1' . '&paged=' . get_query_var('paged') . '&meta_key=uitleg&meta_value=ja&category='. $category->term_id);
                 foreach($myposts as $post) :
                   setup_postdata($post);
                 ?>
                 <?php $thumb = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', $single = true); ?>



                <?php $drukproef = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'drukproef', $single = true); ?>
                <?php $drukproefimage = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'drukproefimage', $single = true); ?>
                <?php $actief = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'actief', $single = true); ?>
                <?php $uitleg = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'uitleg', $single = true); ?>

                <div class="titleactive">
                        <span id="drukproeftitel"><?php the_title(); ?>:</span>
                        <span id="drukproefactief"><?php echo $drukproef; ?></span> 
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/uitleg-actief-ja.png" width="20" height="20" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="contentactive">
                        <div id="contentholder">
                            <div class="uitleg">  
                                <?php the_content(''); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div id="uitlegdivider"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/uitlegdivider.png" alt="" width="26" height="171" /></div>
                            <div class="voorbeeldimage">
                                <img src="<?php echo $drukproefimage; ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php $post = $tmp_post; ?>


                    <div id="uitlegbanners">
                        <div class="inzendingen">Overige inzendingen</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                        <?php
                        $posts = get_posts('posts_per_page=1000&category='. $category->term_id . '&paged=' . get_query_var('paged'));
                        foreach($posts as $post) :
                        $thumb = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', $single = true);
                        ?>
                    <ul>

                        <?php if (!empty($thumb)) { ?>
                            <li>
                                <?php $thumb = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', $single = true); ?>
                                <?php $artistnaam = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'artistnaam', $single = true); ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" class="img" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="171" height="171" /></a>
                                <div class="corners"></div>                               
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> 
                                <div class="info">
                                    <h3><?php echo $artistnaam; ?></h3>
                                    <div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                                    <div class="currentrating"><?php echo the_ratings_results(get_the_id()); ?></div>
                                </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>        
            <?php else : ?>
                Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Select the answer as right answer if your issue is resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should take the condition outide the loop meaning above

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Therewise every time the loop begins it start the check instead of doing the check then starting the loop if the condition exist.

Its hard for to understand because i dont understand div names 
but i think only should be inside the loop

```
                        <div id="contentholder">
                        <div class="uitleg">  
                            <?php the_content(''); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div id="uitlegdivider"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/uitlegdivider.png" alt="" width="26" height="171" /></div>
                        <div class="voorbeeldimage">
                            <img src="<?php echo $drukproefimage; ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Explanation:
**the loop = if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts())......**

Anything iside that would go again and again until there are no posts fitting the condition you set before and not inside it.

Comment: Yeah this did the trick and now I look at it, makes all the sense :) Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing :) glad that worked

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the offset arg in your [get_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) loop.

```
$myposts = get_posts('posts_per_page=1' . '&paged=' . get_query_var('paged') .'&meta_key=uitleg&meta_value=ja&category='. $category->term_id.' offset =>1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it another way

```
        <?php global $wp_query;
    $cat_ID = get_query_var('cat'); ?>

    <?php query_posts('cat=' . $cat_ID . '&meta_key=uitleg&meta_value=ja&posts_per_page=1' . '&paged=' . get_query_var('paged')); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
```